# React Native - The development server returned response code: 503

Tags: react-native

when I try to `react-native run-android` my project I keep receiving this error although yesterday it worked just fine and today -without any changes- this error appears out of nowhere!
if it helps when I execute `react-native run-android` first a different error shows up which I fixed it but I don't know why it's still there and when I refresh the app this 503 error shows up!

[here's a screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ9xZ.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

This is probably caused by your phone proxy, and the error got nothing to do with `rn`,  check backend too.

Comment: Thanks man, you saved my life. i was using my company proxy and it caused the problem. i wish i could upvote you bu i can't.

Answer (score 0):

For those who might still have this problem, 
if you look at the error you will see that this error body is generated by server not react native.
and I found out that in my case the problem was cased by our company proxy,
in order to fix it simply turn off your proxy. hope it helps you.

Comment: Yeah, mohammad you're right, my problem was caused by proxy too. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but for those of you who work in organizations that have proxy set up on employees' computers, you might face the same issue. If you do, just turn off the proxy.

Answer (score -2):

It might due to your packager server did not started properly . You can try with 'npm install' again followed by 'npm start' and then 'react-native run-android'